# Android determine area region with given position X and Y

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-canvas, unityscript

I want to know where user touched on the screen and there are four regions that I've separated. How can I check which whether screen user touched?

My screen can be change dynamically with difference size of screens.

```
width // screen width
height // screen height
```

Here is my code but it works with only a square screen.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        if(y<=x&&width-y-1>=x){
            dirx = "UP";
        }
        if(y>=x&&height-x-1>=y){
            dirx = "LEFT";
        }
        if(y>=x&&height-y-1<=x){
            dirx = "DOWN";
        }
        if(y<=x&&width-y-1<=x){
            dirx = "RIGHT";
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Screen example**

[image]

Comment: try to get an angle between a horizontal line and a line segment going thru your touch point and center of your screen,  tip: Math.atan2, the rest is obvious

Comment: your image perfectly matches what i mean,  use Math.atan2, the lines you have drawn are the angle boundaries for your sections